# Powerapps Multiple If Statements

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, powerapps

I am trying to get multiple If statements working based on a sharepoint value i can get it working as one If statement but not as multiple see examples

Working

```
If(
IsBlank(LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,
        Task_Owner = Label3.Text && Task_Type_Short="FLT" && 
Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy- 
mm-dd"))),Color.AliceBlue,Color.DarkRed)
```

Example of what is'nt working

```
If(
IsBlank(LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,
        Task_Owner = Label3.Text && Task_Type_Short="FLT" && 
Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy- 
mm-dd"))),Color.YellowGreen,


IsBlank(LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,
        Task_Owner = Label3.Text && Task_Type_Short="MCE" && 
Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy- 
mm-dd"))),Color.DarkGreen,Color.DarkRed)
```

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is it not working? Syntax seems fine.

Comment: I am after the highlighted boxes to be DarkRed and DarkGreen depending on condition (i.e "FLT" or "MCE") but they are all just yellowgreen

Comment: If there are all YellowGreen then that means your first conditional is matching for all. Hard to help further with just the info above. You will need to do some debugging, and focus on getting just one conditional working. You mentioned in your question that the solo if worked, so does that mean you had cells in AliceBlue and some in DarkRed?

Comment: This works and gives me the first If condition

If(
    IsBlank(LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,
            Task_Owner = Label3.Text && Task_Type_Short="FLT" && 
    Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = T 
    Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
                    )),Color.AliceBlue,Color.DarkRed) - See above

Comment: Therefore it is always `IsBlank`. You sure that is what you want? Ie the Lookup isn't returning anything.

Comment: Ah no i guess i just need If(LookUp) i will try it out

Comment: OK this gives me what i want for 1 condition but i would like to add a second condition

If(
    IsBlank(LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,
            Task_Owner = Label3.Text && Task_Type_Short="FLT" && Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
                    )),Color.AliceBlue,Color.DarkRed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the result i required

```
    !IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Label3.Text && 
Task_Type_Short="MCE" && Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm- 
dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    )
),
Color.DarkGreen,

!IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Label3.Text && 
Task_Type_Short="A/L" && Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm- 
dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    )
),
Color.MediumPurple,
RGBA(241,244,249, 1)
)
```